# React Native: You have a large list that is slow to update

Tags: react-native, pagination, react-native-flatlist, react-memo

I am trying to implement pagination in React Native using FlatList. I have followed the best practices, yet I am still getting the following error:

VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. Object {
"contentLength": 23651.732421875,
"dt": 1394,
"prevDt": 865,
}

Here is the code:

```
const NewsScreen = ({ isLoading, news, fetchInitialNews, fetchMoreNews, isLoadingMore, hasMoreToFetch }) => {
 
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInitialNews();
  }, []);

  const onEndReached = () => {
    fetchMoreNews();
  };

  return (
      <NewsList
        isLoading={isLoading}
        news={news}
        numSkeletonsToShow={LATEST_NEWS_CONSTANTS.NUM_TO_SHOW}
        contentContainerStyle={STYLES.newsListContentContainer}
        onEndReached={onEndReached}
        isLoadingMore={isLoadingMore}
        hasMoreToFetch={hasMoreToFetch}
      />
  );
};
```

```
const renderNewsItem = ({ item, index }) => (
  <NewsItem news={item} containerStyle={index !== 0 ? GLOBAL_STYLES.cardMargin : null} />
);

const NewsList = ({
  isLoading,
  news = [],
  isLoadingMore,
  contentContainerStyle = {},
  onEndReached,
  hasMoreToFetch
}) => {
  const dummySkeletonArray = Array(numSkeletonsToShow).fill("1");

  const onScrollToEnd = () => {
    if (!isLoadingMore && hasMoreToFetch) {
      onEndReached();
    }
  };

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      //..loading indicator
    );
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={news}
      keyExtractor={(n) => n.url}
      renderItem={renderNewsItem}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      style={GLOBAL_STYLES.flatListContentContainer}
      contentContainerStyle={contentContainerStyle}
      onEndReached={onScrollToEnd}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.2}
      ListFooterComponent={hasMoreToFetch && <ActivityIndicator animating={isLoadingMore} />}
    />
  );
};
```

```
const areEqual = () => true;

const NewsItem = ({ news, containerStyle }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableNativeFeedback viewContainerStyle={containerStyle}>
      <Card>
      </Card>
    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
  );
};

export default memo(NewsItem, areEqual);
```

I have used `memo` and moved the `renderItem` outside the functional component as suggested by many other posts. Still no luck. Thank you for your help!

UPDATE:

The problem was due to conditionally rendering the `ListFooterComponent` (i.e. `ListFooterComponent={hasMoreToFetch && <ActivityIndicator animating={isLoadingMore} />}`). Changing it to `ListFooterComponent={<ActivityIndicator animating={isLoadingMore} />` solves the issue. An issue has been opened by @parse (refer to the comments below) and can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32924).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of **OnEndReached** being called multiple times. Since you are trying to fetch next set of data from server, if onEndReached is called multiple times in a single go, it tries to call from server multiple times. I resolved by having a state to avoid multiple calls:

```
const [loader, setLoader] = useState(false);

const onEndReached = (page) => {
  if (!loader) {
    setPage(page + 1)
  }
}

const loadData = async () => {
  setLoader(true);
  const resp = await fetchMoreNews();
  setLoader(false);
}

<FlatList ...someprops onEndReached={onEndReached} />
```

In some other cases, adding the below code to your Flatlist also works, where n being a small number(in my case 10).

```
initialNumToRender={n}
```

Comment: Hi,

I have that logic implemented as you can see in the code

`if (!isLoadingMore && hasMoreToFetch) {
      onEndReached();
}`

This will only call the `onEndReached` function passed to the `NewsList` only if its not already loading more & there is more data to get. Also, for the `initialNumToRender`, what do I put if I don't exactly know how many news articles I am getting from the API?

Comment: use prop called removeClippedSubviews and initialNumToRender

when to use initialNumberToRender If There Is Pagination Where You Get 50 Data That Time I suggest using this props it'll be more affective with removeClippedSubViews

Comment: onEndReachedThreshold is also extremely useful as props describe when content is half-visible to screen it will invoke onEndReached function.  the setting value of this prop also helps to improve scrolling.

Comment: @VinitBhavsar On Android - the device I am testing on and seeing the error, removeClippedSubviews is true by default. I have also tried the initialNumToRender prop as well. No luck.

Comment: try to change `ListFooterComponent={hasMoreToFetch && <ActivityIndicator animating={isLoadingMore} />}` to `ListFooterComponent={<ActivityIndicator animating={isLoadingMore} />}` and if it works, please let me know! In my case, I have been debugging it all day and found out that when footer prop has no state, it just works fine without the warning.

Comment: @parse YOU ARE A LIFE SAVER! TY, it worked! I do not see the warning anymore after removing the conditional rendering in the ListFooterComponent. However, I applied a marginTop style to the activity indicator. Even if the activity indicator hides when not animation, there is still this weird marginTop. I tried conditionally putting the style but then the warning comes back. For example
`ListFooterComponent={<ActivityIndicator animating={isLoadingMore} style={hasMoreToFetch ? {marginTop: 10} : {}}/>}`. I tried using the `ListFooterComponentStyle` and doing something similar, but same issue.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked! It sounds like a bug there. I have opened an issue on React Native github repo here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32924 please confirm that you are facing the same issue.